# Android: ImageView Border With Buttons

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, border, android-imagebutton

I am looking to make an `ImageView` that I can manipulate with touch (translate, scale and rotate). I currently have one that uses `ScaleType.MATRIX` and can be translated and scaled. I would like to be able to wrap this `ImageView` with a border, and put `ImageButton` objects in the corners to act as a 'close' and 'scale/rotate' button. Much like in the image below (taken from the [Aviary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aviary.android.feather&hl=en) app):

[image: Aviary Example Image]

I cannot figure out where to start with this. In order to manipulate the `ImageView` I need to set the view to `MATCH_PARENT`, and use a `Matrix` to manipulate the drawable within it. But then how am I supposed to wrap the drawable in a border?

Or am I supposed to manipulate the `ImageView` directly instead of the drawable? If so, how would I go about doing that with a `Matrix`?

Comment: I think using a canvas is better for this purpose.

Comment: I have tried using a canvas as well. I do not know how I would have the border wrap around the bitmap that is drawn to the canvas.

Comment: i am also looking for solution... plz help somebody who did this before..

Answer (score 0):

Create a frame layout and add the four buttons on it the add the frame to your layout. Use the onclick of that buttons to create different functions you mention.